# How to mount a secret file from Jenkins into a Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I need to fetch a credentials file from Jenkins and load it into a Kubernetes deployment.
This file needs to be loaded at the beginning, before the pods launch since it's a configuration file.

My idea was, in the Jenkins part, to do something like `withCredentials([file(credentialsId: credentials, variable: 'credentials')]) { }`

And use that variable to create a secret, then use it in a deployment. Right now I can only do this with stringData, something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: 'metadata'
  labels:
    project: 'example'
type: Opaque
stringData:
  TEST: '${TEST}'
```

I would need a way to use this, but with a file, within a Secret.
And to mount it in my deployment, I suppose with the `volumeMounts` option

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit hacky in my opinion. I would rather use a configmap, which you can create with a custom (or search for one) kubernetes operator. Otherwise, a sidecar container could help as well.

https://learnk8s.io/sidecar-containers-patterns